# Append to next position in List

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to write some code for a game I am creating. When the user has completed the game the user's score (`x`) is added to the first position in a list called `scores`.

I need each subsequent attempt of the quiz to be appended to the next position in the list. After three attempts, I would like the program to delete the first item in a list, thus only storing the last three attempts. Here is the code I have written.

```
if myname in students:
    scores = students[myname]
    which = 1
    which-= 1
    if 0 <= which < len(scores):
        scores[which] = x
    elif which != -1:
        print("Invalid Score Number")
else:
     print("Student not found")
```

Comment: Why do you have `which = 1` immediately followed by `which -= 1`? Why not just assign `which = 0`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) to do this easily; just set `maxlen` to your desired maximum length, then new items on the right will push out old items on the left:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque(maxlen=3)
>>> for x in range(5):
    d.append(x)
    print d


deque([0], maxlen=3)
deque([0, 1], maxlen=3)
deque([0, 1, 2], maxlen=3)
deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
```

or vice versa:

```
>>> d.appendleft(5)
>>> d
deque([5, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
```

---

An equivalent with a vanilla list:

```
>>> l = []
>>> for x in range(5):
    l.append(x)
    if len(l) > 3:
        _ = l.pop(0)
    print l


[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

The underscore `_` indicates that we won't be using the `pop`ped value.

Comment: Thanks.Is there a way this can be done using an If statement and .append list. I am new to programming. How would I change my code?

Comment: @learningpython yes, you could `.pop(0)` from your `scores` list if `len(scores) > 3` *(answer now edited with demo)*.

Comment: Sorry struggling to add your code into my program.. where do I add it. Tried but failed. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I know that, but how do I add the code to the `if myname in students:` etc. Thanks

Comment: @learningpython you should keep at it, this is pretty trivial. Learn to experiment in the interpreter.